# Substitution in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, substitution

Elementary Row Operations (EROs) are built around the high school algebra technique of elimination.  Another high school algebra technique for solving linear systems, substitution, doesn't correspond to any combination of EROs.  Why was no ERO defined to mirror the process of substitution?

More generally, why do Linear Algebra courses seem to ignore substitution altogether?  Is there/could there be another discipline that talks about linearity differently, from a starting point of substitution instead of elimination?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is equivalent to the composition of linear functions, and substitution is also just function composition so I don't really see the difference. In fact large parts of linear algebra are about finding the right coordinate system (i.e. the right substitution of basis vectors) in which a problem becomes trivial.